# python get html code of website without wait get all code

Tags: python, urllib

Hello I don't know if it's possible to do it with urllib or another library.
I want to print html code of website in realtime/line by line without wait **download** all website html code and print code

when url lib download a html line i want to print this line
if it's not possible with line, may be with timeout (for example print new download code all 1 second)

thanks for advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

That’s not how source code is loaded from servers, you don’t request it line by line.

In most cases a lib simply makes HTTP requests using an abstraction to the communication layers and the individual packets get assembled at the TCP layer...

If you want to visualize it simply load all the HTML and then print each line individually or use a socket to talk to the server using raw TCP messages, but this will not offer you line by line source code and you’ll have to decode the payloads individually.